# Replace letter in array in specific way

Tags: r, regex, string

I have these vectors:

```
 texts=c("AANAAA","NNAAAA","AAAAAA", "NAAANN")

 letter=c("C","C","G","T","P","D")
```

I am trying to replace `N` for each element in `texts` and replace it with a character from second array `letter` by position.

Take `"AANAAA"`, the `N` at third position should be replaced by the third element of `letter`, i.e. `G`

My expected output is:

```
texts=c("AAGAAA","CCAAAA","AAAAAA", "CAAAPD")
```

I was trying `gsub` and a `for` loop

```
for (i in 1:6) {
   for (j in 1:4)
      gsub("N",letter[i],texts[j][i])
}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in base R like this. No loop is required. `gregexpr` extracts a list of positions in `texts` where matched. We then replace characters at those positions with corresponding characters in `letter` using `regmatches<-`.

```
 m <- gregexpr("N", texts, fixed = TRUE)
 regmatches(texts, m) <- lapply(m, \(i, x) x[i], letter)
```

Output

```
>  texts 
[1] "AAGAAA" "CCAAAA" "AAAAAA" "CAAAPD"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using loops, split texts into letters and replace "N" with corresponding letter:

```
sapply(strsplit(texts, ""), function(i){
  ix <- which(i == "N")
  i[ ix ] <- letter[ ix ]
  paste(i, collapse = "")
})
# [1] "AAGAAA" "CCAAAA" "AAAAAA" "CAAAPD"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `tidyverse/purrr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

texts=c("AANAAA","NNAAAA","AAAAAA", "NAAANN")
letter=c("C","C","G","T","P","D")

texts %>% 
  map(~ str_split(.x, "") %>% unlist %>% 
        map2_chr(letter, ~ if_else(.x == "N", .y, .x))) %>% 
  map_chr(~ str_c(.x, collapse = ""))

#> [1] "AAGAAA" "CCAAAA" "AAAAAA" "CAAAPD"
```